# Unable to obatin device screenshot with UI automator when A process is running on that app

Tags: android-uiautomator

I am unable to get the device screenshot while automating my native application on android only when Some file is downloading on my native application. What can be the issue. Getting error : Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!
Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!

Comment: I answered you below but I wanted to ask you how you are getting the screenshot. For some reason my code doesn't take the screenshot nor produces an error.

Comment: I am also getting this error sometimes while attempting to capture the screen of my app...but the automation is not running....so it must be something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use UiAutomator when some other activity is using your app. For example if you are running the tests you can't use UiAutomatorViewer at the same time.